# Java / JavaFX exception -- how to determine fault

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, javafx-2

So I'm getting an exception and none of my code is listed in it.

Is there a simple (quick, easy) way to tell whether the issue is in my code or if it's (probably not) possibly a bug in Java, in this case, JavaFX?

My code is a wrapper to a long-running script (a Lua script) that also itself (the Lua script) calls out to Bash scripts, in case that information is of any use.

The exception seems to be fairly easy to reproduce, by clicking around the screen while a particular portion of the scripts are running--I think when it's doubly shelled out to both Lua and Bash--as a matter of fact.  (I have a thread, a Runnable, that reads the output stream from the Lua script and I generally have full control of my JavaFX GUI, logging results from the scripts, etc., except of course, once this exception occurs.)

Here's my exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickCounter.access$7600(Scene.java:2985)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.preProcess(Scene.java:3081)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8400(Scene.java:3051)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3302)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3164)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3119)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1559)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2261)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:82)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Thanks for any pointers on how to do this in general (and in this case, specifically)!

UPDATE: What I'd like to know is: Should I be debugging *my* code to determine the cause of this?  Or is it clearly a JavaFX bug?  If so, I'll report it to the Oracle team responsible.

Comment: Do you read or modify an active scene graph off the JavaFX application thread?  Or do you tie up the JavaFX application thread for long periods of time?

Comment: Well, I call an "exception occurred" dialog that is on the active Scene graph **from the Runnable doing the script processing** and of course I 'operate' the scene graph by setting effects, updating textfields, etc. **from the main JavaFX app thread**.  I think I understand which threads you mean, and I believe by 'JavaFX application thread' you mean the latter one--the one that continues running, while my 'runnable' goes off and snags the stream from the ProcessBuilder process.  As to 2nd question, *no*, if I am understanding which 'JavaFX application thread' you mean; if swapped, then *yes*!

Comment: You should use [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to `call an "exception occurred" dialog that is on the active Scene graph from the Runnable doing the script processing"`

Comment: Does your mouse have more than 3 buttons?  If so are you [pressing one of the extra buttons](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23671)?

Comment: No, however on the computer where I see the issue most, it's a small Netbook, running in about 1.5GB (looks like 992.1 MiB via report, but I know it has 1.5 GB) of memory, on Ubuntu 12.04 (Unity 2D), the computer itself is a Clevo M810L with an Intel Atom CPU N270 @ 1.60 Ghz (x 2 ? cores?). 32-bit. Plenty of disk space: 160 GB drive. The other issue that may be the problem is I'm putting about 1.6 MB of text into a TextArea control, using `ta.appendText("txt");` for each line. I'm going to try throwing out 99/100 lines and see if that helps--it's also *quite* slow compared to command line run.

Comment: Actually, now that I look at that [bug report you linked to](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23671), it could be that; suspiciously similar to my exception.  The trackpad on this little netbook is quite 'skittish' if you know what I mean.  There are two buttons, left and right.  Plus I am running x86 Ubuntu, just like the reporter of the bug...  Hmmm.  Good catch, thanks jewelsea.  I'll see if I can reproduce it reliably in a small example (on this hardware), when I get a chance, and add my findings to that report.

Comment: UPDATE: I went ahead and added a comment to that bug report with my info. If they need me to narrow it down, I'm sure they'll contact me!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17312/discussion-between-jewelsea-and-likethesky)

Comment: I am getting the exact same exception without running any Lua or Bash scripts. I did not identify the exact problem, yet. Did you step into the NPE already?